# JQuery DataTables - not hide rows on mobile

Tags: jquery, datatables

Is there a way in Jquery Datatables plugin to not hide rows on small screen? Now it hides the overflowed cells and opens on pressing the button. I'd like to have all data visible initially but can't find such option in docs.

UPD1:
Initialization code:

```
$('.schedule_table').DataTable( {
    responsive: true,
    paging: false,
    bFilter: false,
    bInfo: false,
    aaSorting: [],
    columnDefs: [
        { type: 'title-string', targets: [0, 6] },
        { targets: 7, orderable: false }
    ]
} );
```

Now it looks like this:

[image]

Trying to make it look like this INITIALLY

[image]

because I want all data to be visible without need to press the (+) button.

Comment: Please show your DataTables initialization code, markup and/or screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the code below after DataTables initialization code to expand all child rows:

```
$('.schedule_table tbody td:first-child').trigger('click');
```